# ¿Cómo definir un condicional para SOAP en caso de existir un elemento en el array?

Tags: php, wordpress, webservice, soap

Buenas a todos, 
He creado un plugin para web services en wordpress en el que inscribe mediante un formulario pero quiero validar un input con un value en ajax antes de enviarlo y ver si existe ese posible valor en la base de datos.
Hago la consulta pero no consigo establecer el if que diga que si existe "id_usuario" en el array que devuelve la response de la consulta, que haga echo y por ajax muestre un console.log (todo esto funciona salvo el if que siempre me da "no existe" como resultado).

Este es el código:

```
if (isset($_POST['prev_username'])) {

    $params = array();
    $params['id_usuario'] = $_POST['prev_username'];

    try{ 
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
        //creamos el cliente
        $cliente = new SoapClient("XXX", array(
            'login'          => "XXX",
            'password'       => "XXX"
            )
        );
        //hacemos la consulta 

        $resultado = $cliente->consultar_usuarios($params);


        if(isset($resultado->usuarios->id_usuario)){//cuando sólo hay un usuario
            echo "existe";
        }

        else {
            echo "no existe";
        }

    }

    catch (SoapFault $e) { 

        echo $e;

    }
};
```

Esto es lo que recibo cuando pruebo un nombre que existe en SoapUi

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <consultar_usuarios_response xmlns="urn:XXXX">
         <usuarios>
            <administrador_usuario>false</administrador_usuario>
            <id_usuario>XXX</id_usuario>
            <nombre>XXX</nombre>
            <apellido>XXX</apellido>
            <clave>XXX</clave>
            <id_idioma>6</id_idioma>
            <email>XXX</email>
            <dato_adicional_1>XXX</dato_adicional_1>
            <dato_adicional_2>XXX</dato_adicional_2>
            <dato_adicional_3>XXX</dato_adicional_3>
            <telefono>XXX</telefono>
         </usuarios>
      </consultar_usuarios_response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Y esto cuando no existe

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <consultar_usuarios_response xmlns="urn:XXX"/>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme y mil gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a hacer un cast array de la respuesta soap, esto te creará un array asociativo, y podrás hacer las comprobaciones pertinentes.

```
$arr_respuesta = (array) $resultado;
if(isset($arr_respuesta["usuario"])){//cuando sólo hay un usuario
    echo "existe";
}
 else {
   echo "no existe";
}
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar esto.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el sistema recomienda no comentar para decir gracias pero es necesario para mí darlas. Funcionó perfectamente y sin problemas. Un saludo!!!

Comment: Disculpe la demora, hacía tiempo que no entraba y ver su respuesta. Me alegro que le haya sido útil el código.